# Terminal strange appearance

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, fonts

Font of the terminal is not rendering properly, I don't know why. Here is the screenshot I attached to it and till now haven't done anything as I don't know what is the problem. Please help as I am not able to read anything. OS using is Ubuntu 18.04

[image: Screenshot of terminal]

PS: My first question please ignore the errors!!

Comment: Please add your OS/Version to your question

Comment: Open the terminal's Preferences and pick a monospace font.